# I couldnt call the function inside the server script multiple times from client script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I'll give you a brief summary of the problem with the code snippets. I have 2 files, one is for HTML and CSS scripts and the other is for nodejs implementations of the things I need.

I do have several buttons, where each corresponds to a distinct integer value. Following is a simplified representation of that:

```
<button id ="btn1" value = "11" onclick = "myFunc(11)"><a href ="#" nowrap>Do Task A</a></button>
<button id ="btn2" value = "12" onclick = "myFunc(12)"><a href ="#" nowrap>Do Task B</a></button>
<button id ="btn3" value = "13" onclick = "myFunc(13)"><a href ="#" nowrap>Do Task C</a></button>
```

Here, when you click a button it should call a user defined function "myFunc()" with a distinct argument like 11,12, or sth like that.

As I am a new to this topics, I tried to read docs about this and figured out some points. There is only 1 missing part of that. I do have a port which is listening and I know it's port number etc., but I couldnt find a continuous way to run the following code:

```
    var net = require('net');
    let setval = 1234; //just some number

    var ip_listen = ...; //ip of the port listening
    var port_listen = ...; // port number 
    var buf = new Buffer(1024);
    buf.writeInt32LE(setval, 0); //max value to send 2147483647

    let client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(port_listen, ip_listen , () => {
        console.log("Connected");

        client.write(buf, () => {});
    });
```

The above code is inside my app.js file and when I use the command

```
node app.js
```

It sends the value 1234 for once. I couldnt obtain a way to invoke that as a function. For example when I press 'Do Task A', I want to send the value 11 via myFunc() ---> myFunc(11); , if you could help me or at least show me a reasonable approach, I would appreciate that.